# Vuetify: Using v-tooltip within a v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to use the v-tooltip in a v-for but I think my binding is incorrect, and blocking it from rendering.  I've used this outside of the v-for and it works as expected:

```html
<div v-for="item in items">
    <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            Hover to View
        </template>
        <span>{{ item.name }} </span>
    </v-tooltip>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `v-bind` and `v-on` inside the `template` like this:

`<span v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">Hover to View</span>`

In your example:

```html
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <span v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">Hover to View</span>
    </template>
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</div>
```

Comment: It also requires a v-bind:key prop. ie. <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">